# ggnet2: edge.size by weight using negative values

Tags: r, networking, ggplot2, attributes

I'm plotting a network using ggnet2. My network has weights that range from -1 to 1. I'm trying to find a work around for somehow coloring (or line typing) those values that are negative so I can distinguish them from those values that are positive.

Here is so sample data:

```
n <- data.frame(event1 = c(-0.2,0.8,0.4),
                event2 = c(0.34,-0.17,0.3),
                event3 = c(0.2,0.1,-0.73),
                row.names = letters[1:3])
net <- network(net,
              matrix.type = "bipartite",
              ignore.eval = FALSE,
              names.eval = "weights")
```

Then when I go to plot it like so:

```
ggnet2(net,label = TRUE, edge.size = "weights")
```

I get an error because of the negative values: Error in ggnet2(bip, label = TRUE, edge.size = "weights") : 
  incorrect edge.size value

Does anyone have ideas of how to make those edges stand out in some way? I was thinking I could add another sig figure to each like a "1" at the end so I could out those values specifically but I can't figure out how to set the code to color specific edges or change the line type of specific edges. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a color for negative and positive edges values. For example:

```
n <- data.frame(event1 = c(-0.2,0.8,0.4,0),
                event2 = c(0.34,-0.17,0.3,0),
                event3 = c(0.2,0.1,-0.73,0),
                row.names = letters[1:4])
net <- network(n,
              matrix.type = "bipartite",
              ignore.eval = FALSE,
              names.eval = "weights")

col = c("actor" = "grey", "event" = "gold")
set.edge.attribute(net, "color", ifelse(net %e% "weights" > 0, "green", "red"))
ggnet2(net, color = "mode", palette = col, label = TRUE, edge.color = "color")
```

For more information and examples you can check here:
[ggnet2: network visualization with ggplot2](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/#edge-size-and-color)